# Data in SAS but stuck with logic

Tags: sql, sas

I am using SAS Data Integration Studio(Can be SAS Code or SQL Code) trying to solve one of the business rules given. The business rule is:
To find out the Staff claimed for the same expense type, AND date purchase within 30 days(For example, one person buy toner every week, buying the same)(expense type)

I have data in this format:

```
StaffNo|Date      |Trip    |Desc  |  InvoiceNumber  | ExpenseType  | Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |01JAN2015 |A       |XX    | ZXC             |100           |50
1      |05JAN2015 |A       |XX    | ZXC             |100           |50
1      |02FEB2015 |A       |XX    | ZXC             |100           |50
1      |03APR2015 |B       |YY    | PPP             |90            |1000
1      |02MAY2015 |B       |YY    | PPP             |90            |1000
2      |01OCT2017 |C       |LO    | 123             |55            |777
2      |02JAN2018 |D       |HI    | 456             |66            |888
2      |02MAY2018 |E       |LL    | 789             |44            |11
3      |11MAR2016 |F       |PO    | 99AA            |122           |88.5
3      |13MAR2016 |G       |PO    | 99AA            |122           |88.5
3      |31DEC2016 |H       |PO    | 99AA            |122           |88.5
```

Sorry for the misalignment above, copy paste it to your notepad will have the proper alignment.

Here is the thing, based on the sample record, i need to find out for Staff Number 1 to 3 that purchased the same ExpenseType item within 30 days. If found out, create a flag with value 'Y' with column named called 'RepeatPurchase' for all records that have this pattern.

In layman term, i want to find out the same StaffNo that purchases the same ExpenseType within 30 days and there is no rules stating to compare the first record against the 2nd or the last record.

Do take note that the date might range from 1 day difference to 10 years difference for next row record, not necessarily to be in below Date pattern as below is just a sample.

I couldn't think of the way to do this. Any advice/guide given is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One method in SQL uses `exists`.  The logic is something like this:

```
proc sql;
    select d.*,
           (case when exists (select 1
                              from data d2
                              where d2.staffno = d.staffno and
                                    d2.ExpenseType = d.ExpenseType and
                                    d2.date < d.date and
                             )
                 then 1 else 0
            end) as repeat_purchase
    from data d;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, by using ur code and removing the additional 'and', i am getting error Subquery evaluated more than a row, which means there are duplicate records when trying to do comparisons.

Comment: @B.Dick . . . When I read the question at first, I thought you wanted to filter out those rows, so I wrote the query using `where`.  Then I realized you want a flag, moved the logic, and didn't finish the `case` expression.  Good morning, wherever you are.